# blank button on the sims 3 mailbox

Tags: the-sims-3

Hello so there's a glitch on my game that I pressed Shift+Click on a mailbox, do Force NPC and then there is a blank button on the screen. Is it a game or a glitch?

Comment: Why can't anyone answer this question? It's been like 2 days...

Answer (score 1):

It's a glitch. Type in your `testingcheatsenabled true` cheat again and change the your needs from what they are set on to the other then change them back. Type in your cheat again and then do your BOX cheat. It should be correct after that. My neighbor had this problem and this is how she said she for got rid of it.